# Rebranding: how do I redirect my website to a new domain, and blog to a subdomain?

Tags: seo, htaccess, 301-redirect, apache2, shared-hosting

I have a website that I am rebranding and using a new domain name for. Right now it is primarily a blog hosted at the root.

I am going to be redirecting from `www.old.com` to `www.new.com`, and I also want to move my blog to `blog.new.com`. Currently `www.old.com` doesn't serve any subdomains.

Based on the research I've done, it would seem that I need to use 301 redirects because these should be permanent.  I just don't really know what I need to do to setup these redirects. Should I use `mod_rewrite`?

My sites are hosted on Dreamhost so any Apache configuration that I would need to do I believe I'd have to do in an `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the following code will be placed in a file called `.htaccess` in your root web directory and mod_rewrite enabled on your server.

Changing the domain is easy to do. The following snippet should do it:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To move your blog you can use the following snippet (assuming your blog is in a subdiretory called `/blog`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.old\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.new.com/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: First part looks OK. I think his blog is currently in the root directory of `www.old.com` and he wants to redirect that to `blog.new.com`, so you might want to modify the second part. Hopefully he adds new content to the root of `www.new.com` or he'll end up with duplicate content issues.

Comment: Yep. I had that in my brain but it apparently didn't make it to y fingers.

Comment: Most of the time I have to edit questions in order to fully grasp them, and sometimes that still doesn't make it to my fingers ;-)

Comment: As far as I know, if he 301 redirects his old site to his new site, he won't have to worry about duplicate content issues.

Comment: @IvovanderVeeken That was referring to the OP redirecting `www.old.com`, where the blog was located, to `www.new.com`, and also moving the blog to `blog.new.com` - the two would need to be different in order to avoid duplicate content.

Comment: @IvovanderVeeken No worries - this one was a bit confusing ;-)

Comment: Well, it actually just came down to a text field in Dreamhost for my Domain to tell it where to redirect. According to the Dreamhost wiki, this does a 301.  I marked this as correct because this would be the other way to do it correctly.  Thanks for the help.